# Unable to fetch data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In the below given program Iam inserting imei_number in the table .However I have to retrieve the inserted data and display it in different method.Please guide.thanks in advance

onCreate()
{

```
try {
     imeiDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(IMEI_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

     imeiDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
     IMEI_TABLE_NAME +" (IMEI_number_db VARCHAR);");

     imeiDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + IMEI_TABLE_NAME +" Values ("+IMEI_number_db+");");

     Cursor c = imeiDB.rawQuery("SELECT IMEI_number_db FROM " + IMEI_TABLE_NAME , null);

     if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                     IMEI_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IMEI_number_db"));

                    }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
     }



} catch (SQLiteException se ) {
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
} finally {
     if (imeiDB != null) 
        imeiDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + IMEI_TABLE_NAME);
        imeiDB.close();
}

    }
```

/******************************/

```
fetch the data in another method

private collectdata()
    {
         String IMEI_number ="";
        Cursor c = imeiDB.rawQuery("SELECT IMEI_number_db FROM " + IMEI_TABLE_NAME , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                     IMEI_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IMEI_number_db"));

                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }



    }
```

Comment: Does value inserted into the Table?

Comment: is IMEI_number_db is variable of String type ?? or just a "IMEI_number_db" string

Comment: @shaft: yes, the value is getting inserted

Comment: @rajpara : yes its a String type

Comment: any error or exception you are getting ?

Comment: @Shweta :IMEI_number = c.getString(0);

Answer (score 0):

The only one column do you search in the query is IMEI_number_db, so the cursor only has one column. You should change this:

```
IMEI_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IMEI_number_db"));
```

For this:

```
IMEI_number = c.getString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code.

```
IMEI_number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IMEI_number_db"));
```